# Is there a hairdresser or any place to change appearance?

Tags: the-secret-world

In the Secret World, I am aware of clothes shops in game but is there a hairdresser/barber shop style building where I can change my hair colour/style or any other place that allows me to change the appearance of my character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional abuse of Google (and assistance from Shinrai) shows that there isn't a barber yet but [that there are plans to add one sometime after the launch](http://www.thesecretworld.com/news/post_launch_character_customisation).

Running around the three major cities I have found a barber shop that is 'under construction':

[image: London Barber Shop - closed]

So it would seem that yes there [will be at some point](http://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?t=37697). Looks like it will come in three parts: a barbershop, a tattooist, and some kind of appearance changing cosmetic surgeon of some description.

Comment: Here's an OFFICIAL source on the matter: http://www.thesecretworld.com/news/post_launch_character_customisation